# HttpContext, alternative approach to Context.Request.Unvalidated for pre .Net 4.5 servers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in my project as per below which takes a `HttpContext` object and returns a `string`.

```
//returns the xml document as string
private static string GetXmlReceiptFromContext(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);        
    return context.Request.Unvalidated.Form.Get("status");
}
```

The result of this is ultimately passed into a very important method that requires this string.

It appears that `Context.Request.Unvalidated` is only available from .Net 4.5.
I need to alternative approach to this method for our servers which do not have .Net 4.5 and will be making use of this assembly.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of accessing and returning the status parameter who's value will be an XML Document from the context without using Context.Request.Unvalidated?

**edit**

This is not for a webform or MVC project, we have developed a class library whch we ideally want to contain all the payment related features within the assembly, i.e. single responsibility, our front end apps which will be using this do not need to know about the payment side of things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740944/how-do-i-disable-request-validation-without-setting-requestvalidationmode-to-2-0

Comment: @generalexception i'd be very carefull to use that. It disables request validation for the entire application, which is probably not what SelectDistinct is after.

Comment: @martennis If you scroll down the page a bit I think you'll find you can disable just for a single page !!

Comment: Which framework are you using? They all have different filters to "protect" you.

Comment: We need to code this to work with 4.0

Answer (score 5):

I don't know weither you are using MVC or Web Forms/Web Pages, but there are several solutions available for you. Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info about disabling request validation.

Web Forms: add `<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>` to the top of your page to disable validation for a single page (other options for more pages/parts of an application are in the MSDN page).

MVC: add attribute `[ValidateInput(false)]` to the top of your action OR add an `[AllowHtml]` attribute to the property in the model you are binding to.

Comment: This wont work unless you set the requestvalidationmode="2.0" in the web.config.

Comment: @generalexception thank you, i misread the article a little bit :)

Comment: @martennis Thanks for your answer, this would indeed work however we need this a level lower as we have to contain this within a class library and don't want to have to implement this into each web application which makes use of our library. See update to question

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BinaryRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.binaryread%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and parse the raw request body yourself. See the RawPostValues() method below.

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(GetXmlReceiptFromContext(context));
        context.Response.Write("</ br>");
        context.Response.Write(GetXmlReceiptFromContext(context));
    }

    //returns the xml document as string
    private static string GetXmlReceiptFromContext(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
        return RawPostValues(context)
            .SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("status", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Value;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> RawPostValues(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod != "POST") yield break;

        var tmpPosition = context.Request.InputStream.Position;
        string[] formElements;

        try
        {
            formElements = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(
                context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.ContentLength))
                .Split('&');

            if (formElements.Length < 1) yield break;
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = tmpPosition;
        }

        foreach (var element in formElements)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element)) continue;

            var key = element.Substring(0, element.IndexOf('='));
            var value = element.Substring(key.Length + 1, element.Length - key.Length - 1);
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Some quick smoke tests with Fiddler2 revealed that this works. You may have to hammer out some kinks.

**Request**

```
POST http://localhost:48707/Handler1.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:48707
Content-Length: 19
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

status=<b>oops!</b>
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 05:29:26 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
Connection: Close

<b>oops!</b>
```